# LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid and pullRefresh appears to not be working?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've been trying to implement pullRefresh on LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid. It seems to be working for LazyVerticalGrid but not for Staggered. The pull actions are not registering it seems. Can anyone spot an issues with my implementation or can confirm it's a bug that would be great.

This is my code

```
val isRefreshing = viewModel.catalogLoading.observeAsState()
val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(
   isRefreshing.value == true,
   { viewModel.refreshCatalog() },
)

Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .pullRefresh(pullRefreshState)
            .background(background)
    ) {
        LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
            columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
            verticalItemSpacing = 8.dp,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            state = rememberLazyStaggeredGridState(),
            content = {
                items(catalog.value?.threads?.count() ?: 0) { index ->
                    Thread(
                        viewModel = viewModel,
                        thread = catalog.value?.threads?.get(index),
                        navController = navController
                    )
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(
                    start = 16.dp,
                    end = 16.dp
                )
        )
        PullRefreshIndicator(
            isRefreshing.value == true,
            pullRefreshState,
            Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter)
        )
    }
```